# The search function under the next.js framework cannot be realized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, search, next.js

I'm trying to make a webpage with next.js, and I'm having some problems with the search function.If I remove the line (index)selectedTab === 'tab', my search works fine, whenever I enter text in the search field, it excludes data that does not contain that text, but if I add selectedTab === 'tab' line, this function will disappear. In my test, when I search with selectedTab === 'tab', the onInputEvent and filter functions in the search code will not be used When it comes to execution, I don't quite understand why this happens. I hope you guys can help me out, please.

index.tsx :

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Script from 'next/script'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {useEffect} from "react";//++
//import '@/component/category-context';//??
import { Console } from 'console'
import courseData from "@/course_data/index.json";


  export default function HomePage() {//++
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('tab1');
    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <div className={styles.header}>
            <h2>
              <Link href="/">元智課程網</Link>
            <input type="search" id={styles.search} className="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="請輸入課名、老師、系所" />
            <Link href='/' id={styles.searchBtn}><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/></svg>
            </Link>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <p id={styles.loginNav}>登入&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
              <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"/>
            </svg>
          </p>
        </Head>
        <div>
      <ul style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab1' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none'
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab1')}
        >
          工程學院
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab2' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab2')}
        >
          管理學院
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab3' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab3')}
        >
          人文社會學院
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab4' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab4')}
        >
          資訊學院
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab5' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab5')}
        >
          電機通訊學院
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab6' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab6')}
        >
          醫護學院
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr color='lightblue'></hr>
      <ul style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab7' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab7')}
        >
          通識教學部
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab8' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab8')}
        >
          軍訓室
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab9' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab9')}
        >
          體育室
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab10' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab10')}
        >
          國際語言文化中心
        </li>
        <li className={styles.bt}
          style={{
            background: selectedTab === 'tab11' ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            listStyle: 'none',
          }}
          onClick={() => setSelectedTab('tab11')}
        >
          全球事務處
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h1><br/></h1>
      <table className="order-table">
        <tbody>
          {selectedTab === 'tab1' && <div>
                      {courseData["300"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      
                    </div>}
          {selectedTab === 'tab2' && <div>
                      {courseData["505"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      
                    </div>}
          {selectedTab === 'tab3' && <div>
                      {courseData["600"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      
                     </div>}
          {selectedTab === 'tab4' && <div>
                      {courseData["304"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      
                    </div>}
          {selectedTab === 'tab5' && <div>
                      {courseData["310"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                      
                    </div>}
            {selectedTab === 'tab6' && <div>
                      {courseData["A21"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))} 
                    </div>}
                    {selectedTab === 'tab7' && <div>
                      {courseData["901"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}               
                    </div>}
                    {selectedTab === 'tab8' && <div>
                      {courseData["903"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </div>}
                    {selectedTab === 'tab9' && <div>
                      {courseData["904"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </div>}
                    {selectedTab === 'tab10' && <div>
                      {courseData["906"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </div>}
                    {selectedTab === 'tab11' && <div>
                      {courseData["907"].map((course, index)=>(
                      <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{course.courseName}<br/></td>
                          <td>{course.courseYear}<br/></td>
                          <td>老師：{course.courseTeacher}</td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </div>}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

      </div>
    );
    
  }
```

category-context.js(search) :

```
if(typeof window === 'object'){
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  // 建立 LightTableFilter
  var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;
    
    // 資料輸入事件處理函數
    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      console.log("input");
      _input = e.target;
      var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
      Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
        Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
        });
      });
    }

    // 資料篩選函數，顯示包含關鍵字的列，其餘隱藏
    function _filter(row) {
      console.log("display");
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
      // 初始化函數
      init: function() {
        console.log("init");
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
        Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
        });
      }
    };
  })(Array.prototype);

  // 網頁載入完成後，啟動 LightTableFilter
  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      console.log(6);
      LightTableFilter.init();
    }
  });

})(document);
}
```

somebody suggested me use state to done it, but I have no idea how to do it.